# Installing Drupal - missing extension 'gd'

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, php-extension

I'm attempting to install Drupal on an Windows / Apache / PHP box.  When running the install script 'install.php' I'm told that the extension `gd` is not installed.

My PHP ini file has it enabled:

```
...
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
...
```

I have restarted the server.

Looking inside the install script I can see it is using `if(extension_loaded ('gd'))` to discover the extension, which returns **false**. `phpinfo();` only mentions it within the 'PHP Credits' section at the bottom.

I've followed all the instructions I can find, all of which boil down to uncommenting it in the php.ini file.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it possible that while you're enabling this extension - it's really not installed?

Comment: I'm not aware that extensions are 'installed' in PHP, merely referenced.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @m.edmondson What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a 'read the manual' moment.

I hadn't set the default extension directory via:

`extension_dir = C:\php\ext`

as I *assumed* it would be relative within the downloaded installation. I eventually discovered this by reading the apache logs.